# Open multiple images using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using a python notebook. In it, I have code that creates images, and am using `image.show()` 
for debugging purposes. However, this has the disadvantage that I cannot name the image, since it has a temporary file name. I am then using `image.save("name.png")` to save the images with different names, and then using `Image.open("name.png")` to open it. However, when I do this, only the last image is actually opened. What do I need to do so that I can call Image.open on several images and they all open? For example if I do:

```
image = Image.fromarray( ... )
image.save("original.png")
Image.open("original.png")

image = Image.fromarray( ... )
image.save("reconstruction.png")
Image.open("reconstruction.png")
```

only "reconstruction.png" shows.

If I use Image.show() after each of them

```
image = Image.fromarray( ... )
image.show()

image = Image.fromarray( ... )
image.show()
```

it will work, but they will have a temporary name, which is meaningless, and if I end up with 7-8 open images I want an easy way to track what is what.

Comment: why can't you use `Image.open(temporary_name)` ? Your problem is unclear. Show code.

Comment: I can use Image.show(), and it will open a window with the image but with a temporary name that does not mean anything. I want a meaningful temporary name so that if I end up with 7-8 images I can make sense of them without having to keep track of what is what.

Comment: When you `open` a file, you need to assign it to something so you can use it later. I don't know how you're getting `show` to work at all with the code you've provided.

Comment: I am just using image = Image.fromarray(
        tile_raster_images(
            Train,
            img_shape=(28, 28),
            tile_shape=(10, 10),
            tile_spacing=(1, 1)
        )
    )
    image.show()

Answer (score 2):

[`Image.show()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show) is mainly for debugging use:

> Displays this image. This method is mainly intended for debugging purposes.
>
> On Unix platforms, this method saves the image to a temporary PPM file, and calls the xv utility.
>
> On Windows, it saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and uses the standard BMP display utility to show it (usually Paint).

You can give a `title` parameter, but it doesn't show on Windows:

> title – Optional title to use for the image window, where possible.

You can use different names for image variable to keep track of them inside Python:

```
image1 = Image.fromarray( ... )
image1.save("original.png")
Image1.open("original.png")

image2 = Image.fromarray( ... )
image2.save("reconstruction.png")
Image2.open("reconstruction.png")

image1.show("image1")
image2.show("image2")
```

Comment: if .show is mainly for debugging use, then what is the recommended way to open an image?

Comment: Use `Image.show()` if you don't mind the temp file, or the title limitation on Windows, otherwise save it to a file and use some other way of opening it.

Answer (score 1):

Also another approach which I used within my IPython/Jupyter/Colab notebook was:

```
import requests
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.display import display

img0 = Image("img0_path", width = 140) 
img1 = Image("img1_path", width = 140) 
img2 = Image("img2_path", width = 140) 
img3 = Image("img3_path", width = 140) 

display(img0,img1,img2,img3)
```